# how can I run the for loop for m number of times - Python

Tags: python

how can I run the for loop for "n" number of times

```
c=[1, 2, 5, 10, 25, 50]
m=50
n=3
count=0
for i in c:
    for ii in c:
        for iii in c:
            if (iii*ii*i)==m:
                count+=1
print(count)
```

Count =18

So in the above example, I'm running it 3 times manually. I want to run it for 3 times automatically using any loop function.

Comment: Try to use recursion.

Comment: @rdas I'm trying it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using `itertools.product` and `functools.reduce`:

```
import itertools, functools
c=[1, 2, 5, 10, 25, 50]
m=50

l = [c] * 3
for i in itertools.product(*l):
    if functools.reduce(lambda x,y:x*y, i) == m: 
        print(i)
```

The output is:

```
(1, 1, 50)
(1, 2, 25)
(1, 5, 10)
(1, 10, 5)
(1, 25, 2)
(1, 50, 1)
(2, 1, 25)
...
```

#### How does it work?

`itertools.product`: takes a list of iterables (lists in this case), and produces a cross product of all these lists. In our case, we're creating all the combinations of

```
[1, 2, 5, ...] x [1, 2, 5, ...] x [1, 2, 5 ..]
```

The result is `(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 5)`, etc. Iterating over these combinations is equivalent to a loop within a loop within a loop.

Then, for every combination, we use `reduce` to product the multiplication of these three numbers. Reduce takes a list and a function, and applies this function to all the items in the list - for example `1 * 2 * 5`.

Comment: Thank you so much, its working.
If its possible can you pls explain a little bit.

Comment: Great. If it answers your question, it would be great if you could accept my answer for future generations. I'll also add some explanations.

Comment: sure, do I need to do anything to "accept your answer for future generations"

Comment: To accept an answer in SO, click the grey checkmark next to the answer - turning it to green.